# How to cancel map marker drag action in Flutter

Tags: flutter

Is there a way to return Google maps marker to it's original position after dragging it to a new location? For example, onDragEnd => if (condition) => do something => else => go back to original position...

Answer (score 0):

> ```
>   import 'package:google_maps_place_picker/google_maps_place_picker.dart';
> ```

Add This Package and then try this :

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_place_picker/google_maps_place_picker.dart';
import 'package:google_maps_flutter/google_maps_flutter.dart';

// Your api key storage.
import 'keys.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // Light Theme
  final ThemeData lightTheme = ThemeData.light().copyWith(
    // Background color of the FloatingCard
    cardColor: Colors.white,
    buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
      // Select here's button color
      buttonColor: Colors.black,
      textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
    ),
  );

  // Dark Theme
  final ThemeData darkTheme = ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
    // Background color of the FloatingCard
    cardColor: Colors.grey,
    buttonTheme: ButtonThemeData(
      // Select here's button color
      buttonColor: Colors.yellow,
      textTheme: ButtonTextTheme.primary,
    ),
  );

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Google Map Place Picker Demo',
      theme: lightTheme,
      darkTheme: darkTheme,
      themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
      home: HomePage(),
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
    );
  }
}

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const HomePage({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  static final kInitialPosition = LatLng(-33.8567844, 151.213108);

  @override
  _HomePageState createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  PickResult selectedPlace;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text("Google Map Place Picer Demo"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              RaisedButton(
                child: Text("Load Google Map"),
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.push(
                    context,
                    MaterialPageRoute(
                      builder: (context) {
                        return PlacePicker(
                          apiKey: APIKeys.apiKey,
                          initialPosition: HomePage.kInitialPosition,
                          useCurrentLocation: true,
                          selectInitialPosition: true,

                          //usePlaceDetailSearch: true,
                          onPlacePicked: (result) {
                            selectedPlace = result;
                            Navigator.of(context).pop();
                            setState(() {});
                          },
                          //forceSearchOnZoomChanged: true,
                          //automaticallyImplyAppBarLeading: false,
                          //autocompleteLanguage: "ko",
                          //region: 'au',
                          //selectInitialPosition: true,
                          // selectedPlaceWidgetBuilder: (_, selectedPlace, state, isSearchBarFocused) {
                          //   print("state: $state, isSearchBarFocused: $isSearchBarFocused");
                          //   return isSearchBarFocused
                          //       ? Container()
                          //       : FloatingCard(
                          //           bottomPosition: 0.0, // MediaQuery.of(context) will cause rebuild. See MediaQuery document for the information.
                          //           leftPosition: 0.0,
                          //           rightPosition: 0.0,
                          //           width: 500,
                          //           borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12.0),
                          //           child: state == SearchingState.Searching
                          //               ? Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator())
                          //               : RaisedButton(
                          //                   child: Text("Pick Here"),
                          //                   onPressed: () {
                          //                     // IMPORTANT: You MUST manage selectedPlace data yourself as using this build will not invoke onPlacePicker as
                          //                     //            this will override default 'Select here' Button.
                          //                     print("do something with [selectedPlace] data");
                          //                     Navigator.of(context).pop();
                          //                   },
                          //                 ),
                          //         );
                          // },
                          // pinBuilder: (context, state) {
                          //   if (state == PinState.Idle) {
                          //     return Icon(Icons.favorite_border);
                          //   } else {
                          //     return Icon(Icons.favorite);
                          //   }
                          // },
                        );
                      },
                    ),
                  );
                },
              ),
              selectedPlace == null ? Container() : Text(selectedPlace.formattedAddress ?? ""),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```